# What is the difference between process and a process with multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

[image]

As we can see a process that has the stack, heap, data, text parts in it. As a clear explanation that I got from books and many other resources. All are clear.

When I move to a process with a multi-threading, then these sections dramatically changed. Why?
[image]

Here you can see, stack, data, are the same that is also mentioned in the above diagram.
but we are seeing other parts are also in it. like, files? code?
what does it mean by files and code? anyhow, if we consider 1.files 2.code and read the definitions and accept it. then why didn't the author mention them in the above diagram of the process?

simple is that process is process, why is it different from the above diagram. even both diagrams are the same as a thing (process). why parts are different? I have taken both diagrams from a book. Both diagrams are showing a process. Even when we see a process with a single thread, that is also different from the above diagram of a process?

can anyone explain the difference between a process or a process with a single thread?
Both diagrams should have the same parts in it.

Answer (score 0):

That top picture for single-threaded process:

```
high  stack
      free-address-space
      heap
      data
low   text
```

In a multi-threaded process you get multiple stacks at the top of the address space, with some free address space in between:

```
high  stack thread 1
      free-address-space
      stack thread 2
      free-address-space
      ...
      stack thread N
      free-address-space
      heap
      data
low   text
```

The maximum stack size per thread is fixed (see `ulimit -a`, default is 8MB on Linux), so that the OS can keep creating new stacks for new threads from the top of the address space to the bottom.